# Parse multiple choice list with Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse a multiple choice question to save it into a database.
The multiple choice question has a mix of questions with 2 to 4 choices.

Here is a sample :

```
1) First question with 4 choices ?
a) First choice b) Second choice c) Third choice d) Last choice
2) Second question with only 3 choices ? 
a) First choice b) Second choice c) Last choice
3) True or False ? 
a) True b) False
...
```

I've been trying to parse it in PHP using regular expressions, and here is the expression I've come up with so far :

```
/(?P<q_num>\d{1,3})\)\s?(?P<quest>.+)\n(\s?a\)\s?)(?P<ans_a>.+)(b\)\s?)(?P<ans_b>.+)(c\)\s?)(?P<ans_c>.+)((d\)\s?)(?P<ans_d>.+))?/g
```

But when available, choice D gets merged with choice C (or C + D merges with B in case of 2 choices only) and I can't manage to separate it.

[See it here](https://regex101.com/r/gC0tB1/1)

What would you suggest ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the simple "anything" (`.+`) pattern for an answer option to "anything not containing a '[a-d])'" (`(?:(?![a-d]\)).)+`):

```
/(?P<q_num>\d{1,3})\)\s?(?P<quest>.+)\n

(\s?a\)\s?)(?P<ans_a>(?:(?![a-d]\)).)+)
   (b\)\s?)(?P<ans_b>(?:(?![a-d]\)).)+)
  ((c\)\s?)(?P<ans_c>(?:(?![a-d]\)).)+))?
  ((d\)\s?)(?P<ans_d>(?:(?![a-d]\)).)+))?
/gx
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/gC0tB1/2

NB: I added the `x` modifier to make the expression more readable.